# Differerentiate layout for two devices with same dpi

Tags: android, layout, resolution, galaxy-tab, nexus-7

i have two layout folder: layout-sw800dp and layout-sw600dp so my app use layout-sw600dp for both devices , **Samsung Galaxy Tab 7** and **Nexus 7**,and it makes my fonts and styles bigger for Nexus 7! how can i differentiate layout for this two devices? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: make two folder in res/layout.nexus 7 for layout-large-tvdpi,samsung 10.1 layout-xlarge-mdpi.

Comment: @Hemant : i will try your nice comment. tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** : i have made two layout folders layout-tvdpi for Nexus 7 and layout-mdpi for Samsung galaxy tab 7

Answer (score 1):

you can check the 10 and 7 inch table screen size from the following code

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float widthInInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
float heightInInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi;
double sizeInInches = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(widthInInches, 2)
            + Math.pow(heightInInches, 2));
```

Here sizeInInches gives you the proper inch of the table take 0.5 inch in buffer and give condition according to it like below.

```
boolean is7inchTablet = sizeInInches >= 6.5 && sizeInInches <= 7.5;
```

And whenever you need to check it just check as below.

```
if(is7inchTablet){
    // do whatever for the 7-inch tablet
}else{
    // do whatever for the 10-inch tablet
}
```

Comment: +1 thank you for your quick answer.i knew that i could get device inches as u mention,but it takes long long time to make conditions for each layout for such a complete app! do u have more faster way to solve the issue?

Comment: just you need to write this code in one base activity or any Util class and pass the context. Why you are thinking of writing this code in every class? I have used this in one Util class only and check the condition. Let me edit that....

Comment: if i get your idea well ,i should check this flag whenever i set a layout? so i should check this for every fragments and classes in my app?

Comment: ya you have to other wise you can also go for different layouts as well.

Comment: my problem solved and i've made it by making two layout folders , my big mistake was that i didn't know the proper dpi of devices.